# Real, mathematical "modulo" operation in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Ruby:

```
-2 % 24
=> 22
```

In Postgres:

```
SELECT -2 % 24;
 ?column?
----------
      -2

SELECT mod(-2,24);
 mod
-----
  -2
```

I can easily write one myself, but I'm curious whether Postgres has a real modulus operation, as opposed to remainder after division.

Comment: Would you mind to include in the question what is _a real modulus operation_ or a link?

Comment: In the context of this question, what I call the "modulus" operation returns the number called "r" here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division. Like Common Lisp's `MOD` (as opposed to `REM`). Or Ruby's `Fixnum#%` (as opposed to `Numeric#remainder`). Both of these operations are important, and for a language to support one and not the other is a weakness.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT MOD(24 + MOD(-2, 24), 24);
```

will return 22 instead of -2

Comment: OK. I haven't tried it, but it looks like this also works if the first operand is positive. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I won't find anything easier than:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION modulus(dividend numeric, divisor numeric) RETURNS numeric AS $$
DECLARE
  result numeric;
BEGIN
  divisor := ABS(divisor);
  result  := MOD(dividend, divisor);
  IF result < 0 THEN
    result := result + divisor;
  END IF;
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: The DBMS vendors seem to agree here: Oracle, SQL Server and MySQL return the same thing as Postgres. I wonder if this is somehow specified in the SQL standard

Comment: I could find a shorter solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a belated answer to the side question that a_horse_with_no_name asked:
Yes this is specified in the SQL standard. And the mentioned vendors comply.