# Is there a way to generate hash integer within a predefined range for a string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, consistent-hashing

For sharding I need good hash algorithm. I need to generate hash integer value for string within 0-2^31 range. Is this possible ?

Following answer give a way to generate integer from md5 algorithm.

[Hashing a String to a Numeric Value in PostgresSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809381/hashing-a-string-to-a-numeric-value-in-postgressql/9812029#comment42326057_9812029)

But is there a way to generate this value within a range ?

Comment: what if you apply modulus on the result ?

Comment: yeah, modulo operator `%` almost does, what you need - you just need to take account *negative remainders* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683600/real-mathematical-modulo-operation-in-postgres

Comment: People usually do this on the application side, because in general the application is doing data routing to shards. It's somewhat odd to need this at the database level.

Comment: Need to avoid modulo operator. This is to implement consistent-hashing. I'm trying to implement this as database functions so pgpool can use it. I don't have the luxury to implement it application layer ( such as java ). As design design I need to separate application from postgresql cluster information.

Comment: @Viraj and why do you think, modulo isn't consistent? -- btw in your special case (your range is 0-2^31) you can use bitwise operators too, to extract the lower 31 bit.

Comment: @pozs when you say modulo, i thought `hash(key) mod n` where n is the number of servers. in that case node adding or removal causes re-hasing the data. I need to avoid that. However bitwise operators might be a good starting point to research.

Answer (score 1):

In the function suggested in [Hashing a String to a Numeric Value in PostgresSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809381), the 32 bits range is expressed as the width of the `bit(N)` cast.

It cannot be passed as a parameter because a type modifier must be constant, but to get a fixed 31 bits, you may just adjust  the function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hash_string_into_31_bits(text) RETURNS int AS $$
   select ('x'||substr(md5($1),1,8))::bit(31)::int;
$$ language sql;
```

Then the result will be always 31 bits wide and positive, which is the same thing.